# JavaScript dynamic array with object and array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a problem with creating list with objects in JavaScript: the object is going to contain an Integer value and an array.

The structure will look like this (this code works):

```
var list = [ {
            id : 1234,
            dependencyList : [ {
                id : 2142
            }, {
                id : 5313
            } ]
        }, {
            id : 4312,
            dependencyList : [ {
                id : 2142
            }, {
                id : 5313
            } ]
        } ];
```

The problem is that I want to create this list dynamically, in other words something like this:

```
var list = [];

var object;
object.id=1234;
object.dependencyList = [];
object.dependencyList.push(2222);

list.push(object);
```

This code does not work when I try to `alert(list[0].length)` and it returns 0 and after using JSON.stringify(list) it only returns `[[]]`.

Anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: list[0] is object not an array, in your sample `list[0] == {
            id : 1234,
            dependencyList : [ {
                id : 2142
            }, {
                id : 5313
            } ]
        }`

Comment: `var object = {};` ???

Comment: yep, @megawac, trying set property to undefined object

Comment: Unrelated: Seems to me that your list could look better as a map of arrays: `list = { 1234 : [ 2142, 5313], 4312 : [2142, 5313] };`

Comment: var object = {}; solved it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list[0]` is an object and not an array, which is why you're not seeing anything for `length`. Try:

```
console.log(Object.keys(list[0]).length);
```

Or you could even just `console.log(list[0])` and check your console to ensure that it contains something.

Also, I assume you meant:

```
var object = {};
```

Because otherwise `object` is `undefined` and your script won't work. Another thing you will have to change is:

```
object.dependencyList.push(2222);
```

to:

```
object.dependencyList.push({id: 2222});
```

Comment: var list = [];

var object = {};
object.id=4444;
object.dependencyList = []; 
object.dependencyList.push({id:2222});
  
list.push(object);

Comment: @dag-roger-stokland-rui Not sure why this isn't voted as the answer, though the one that contains half of this answer is...

Comment: Yes, i agree. This answer is more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

Object isn't defined. Do:

```
var object = {};
```

Comment: Though be aware the structure won't be the same as the one you describe, it'll be 
var list = [ {
            id : 1234,
            dependencyList : [ 2142, 5313 ]
        }, {
            id : 4312,
            dependencyList : [ 2142, 5313 ]
        } ];

Answer (score 0):

You should do `list[0].dependencyList.length)` also you shoud change:
`object.dependencyList.push(2222);`
for
`object.dependencyList.push({id: 2222});`

Answer (score 0):

Objects are your friend.

If you need to create a lot of these things, you should probably define how they are shaped in a function.  An advantage of this is that you can then create a setter for adding a dependency that hides the implementation as a push against a particular member variable.

Something like this:

```
function createObject( id ) {
    var object = {};
    object.id = id;
    return object;
}

function createObjectWithDependencies( id ) {
    var object = createObject( id );
    object.dependencyList = [];

    object.addDependency = function( dependentObject ) {
        object.dependencyList.push( dependentObject );
    }

    return object;
}

var list = [];

var object = createObjectWithDependencies( 1234 );
object.addDependency( createObject( 2142 ) );
object.addDependency( createObject( 5313 ) );
list.push( object );

var object = createObjectWithDependencies( 4312 );
object.addDependency( createObject( 2142 ) );
object.addDependency( createObject( 5313 ) );
list.push( object );

console.log( list );
```